# Why can't my discord.js bot receive messages? Updated from v12 to v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to write a bot using discord.js. Everything was working until I updated to the latest version (14.6.0) from 12.5.3 and now my bot can't seem to receive messages. I'm thinking it has something to do with the intents that Discord has implemented but I'm not exactly sure.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but I'm running nodejs version 18.11.0

Here's the relevant part of my code

```
const { Discord, EmbedBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits, Intents, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages] });
client.login('TOKEN');

client.on('message', msg => {
   console.log("RECIEVED MESSAGE")
...
```

I can get the bot to log in, but the message never logs to the console.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I updated to the latest version"_... from which previous version?

Comment: @Phil I'm honestly not sure.. I wrote the bot in 2020 and used it for a few months, now I'm updating the code with new features

Comment: What does your version control say? What was the previous version in your `package.json` file and / or the lock file?

Comment: @Phil Ah, sorry I should have checked there first, it says 12.5.3, will update the post

Comment: you have to use `messageCreate` event instead of `message`. and make sure you have enabled message content intents on discord degelopres portal for you bot.

Comment: I suggest you read both the [v13 migration docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html) and [v14 migration docs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html)

Comment: @Phil thank you! I got it working, I'll update the post

Answer (score 1):

I read the migration docs as suggested by Phil, and here's the solution

for those who run into this problem in the future, here was my solution

```
const { Discord, EmbedBuilder, Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages ], partials: [Partials.Channel] });
client.login('TOKEN');

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
   console.log("RECIEVED MESSAGE")
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `messageCreate` event? From the [v14 migration guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#events)... _"The `message` and `interaction` events are now removed. Use `messageCreate` and `interactionCreate` instead."_

Comment: @Phil You're right, I copied the last five lines from my previous post. I just edited. Thanks for catching that

Comment: So you say you added `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages` and the `Partials.Channel` partial and now you receive messages? None of has them anything to do with normal messages.

Comment: You will also need to add `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` to actually get the content of the message

Answer (score -1):

I am using these options, you may have a try

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES], partials: ['CHANNEL'] });

    client.on('messageCreate', message => {
var args = message.content.split(' ');
```

Comment: I've read that using Intents is bad practice, and we should be using IntentsBitField or GatewayIntentBits

Comment: I don't think there is `Intents` in `v14.6.0` so it won't work.